# ractive components example not working

Tags: components

I'm new to ractive.js and not the best with javascript. I've been working through the examples on the ractive webite and I cannot get this particular example to work. I'm thinking it must be something simple I'm overlooking.

Here is a link to the working example on ractive's website:
http://examples.ractivejs.org/components

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lotuscg/dtzuhe60/10/

Here is my html code. Please see fiddle for script code.

```
 <h1>Chris's Components Example</h1>
 <div id='output'></div>
 <script id='mainTemplate' type='text/ractive'>

 {{#months:i}}
 <div class='box'>
 <!-- the donut chart -->
 <donutchart data='{{data}}' selected='{{id}}' delay='{{ i * 50 }}'
  on-select='select'/>

 <!-- the month name -->
 <div class='label'>{{name}}</div>
 </div>
 {{/months}}


 <!-- {{>donutchart}} -->
 <svg viewBox='0 0 100 100'>
 <g transform='translate(50,50)'>
 {{# getSegments( data ) :i}}
  <polygon on-hover='select:{{id}}' class='donut-segment' fill='{{ colors[ id ] }}'
    opacity='{{ !selected ? 1 : ( selected === id ? 1 : 0.2 ) }}'
    points='{{ getSegmentPoints( ., 20, 50, c ) }}'
   >
 {{/ segments }}
 </g>
 </svg>
 <!-- {{/donutchart}} -->
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated version:

http://jsfiddle.net/dtzuhe60/16/

It failed at the very first line, where the variable `template` was undefined. Apparently, the demo filled that variable beforehand. It also used a legacy version of ractive js where you had to call `Ractive.parse(...)`.

In the updated version, I simply gave the templateIds as argument directly in the constructor:

`DonutChart = Ractive.extend({
  template: "#donutchart",
...
ractive = new Ractive({
  el: '#output',
  template: '#mainTemplate',
...`